# In Eclipse RCP, how do we add a combo control to the main toolbar and update it when a new editor is activated

Tags: eclipse, toolbar, program-entry-point, rcp

Ok, so I have successfully added the combo control to the main toolbar of my eclipse RCP application using the following extension within one of my application's plugins.

```xml
<extension
 point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
<menuContribution
    allPopups="false"
    locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
 <toolbar
       id="com.company.module.toolbar"
       label="Sample">
    <control
          class="com.company.module.ui.ComboToolbarContribution"
          id="zoomControl">
    </control>
</toolbar>
```

I have defined

```java
public class ComboToolbarContribution extends
WorkbenchWindowControlContribution
```

and the above class returns a combo control that is pre-populated with values 100%, 200%, 300%, 400%

This toolbar is enabled for certain types of editors in my application using the visibleWhen clause on the toolbar extension.

Each editor in the application can support a different zoom level, so the content of the combo needs to be updated everytime an editor is activated to reflect the zoom level currently supported by it.

How do I update this combocontrol to reflect the value of the editor that is currently in focus or activated? Is there any hook available to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IPartListener` to listen for changes to the active part.

```java
IWokbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

IPartService partService = window.getPartService();

partService.addPartListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IPartListener#partActivated(IWorkbenchPart part)` . See help [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIPartListener.html)
Also check [this](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/listenin-to-parts/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Greg and Chandra. I was looking more at how to access the combo control added to the toolbar under the main toolbar.I would need to use that mechanism whenever the event of an editor activation happens. Do you have any idea on how to go about it?